# Tax refund return envelope - Should I stamp it?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, new-jersey

NJ requires a return envelope for Non-Resident tax claims (1040NR). However I live abroad and cannot put a stamp on my return mail.

I wonder if they use the envelope without a stamp to mail the check? I'll give an US address for my mailing address so there's no need for international shipment, only domestic.

I considered USPS click & ship service so I can print an online return label, but it's only valid for few days. It seems my only option is good-old mail but can't find a way for the return mail.

I know there are services like taxback.com but they charge $90+processing fee and I already prepared my tax claim, I only need one envelope. I'm not super keen to pay them when I've already done my job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is possible that you are misunderstanding this section of the instructions.

On page 48 of the [Form NJ-1040NR instructions (PDF)](http://www.state.nj.us/treasury/taxation/pdf/current/1040nri.pdf), under *Assembling Your Return*, it says:

> Use the return envelope to mail Form NJ‑1040NR with related enclosures, payment voucher, and check or money order.
>   Send only one return per envelope.

What they mean is that if you received an envelope with your form that New Jersey sent you, use that envelope to mail back your form along with everything that goes with it.  You do not need to send in an empty envelope.  When the tax agencies mail out checks, they have their own mailing system; they will not use an envelope that you send in.